# How to find which file provide(d) the feature in emacs elisp

Tags: emacs, elisp

Currently i am using the **load-history** variable to find the file from which a feature came from.

suppose to find the file the feature **gnus** came from.

I execute the following code in scratch buffer which prints filename and the symbols in separate lines consecutively.

```
(dolist (var load-history)
  (princ (format "%s\n" (car var)))
  (princ (format "\t%s\n" (cdr var))))
```

and then search for "(provide . gnus)" and then move the point to the start of line(Ctrl+A).
The file name in the previous line is the file from which the feature came from.

Is there any thing wrong with this method, or does a better method exist.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't really know what you're trying to do with this, but here are some notes.

- Your method is fine.  Any way to hack your own solution to a problem is good in my book.
- @Tom is correct that you shouldn't really need to do this, because the problem is already solved for you by the help system.  i.e. <kbd>C-h f</kbd>

But that's not so interesting.  Let's say you really want an automatic, more elegant solution.  You want a function -- `locate-feature` with this signature:

```lisp
(defun locate-feature (feature)
  "Return file-name as string where `feature' was provided"
  ...)
```

### Method 1 `load-history` approach

#### I'll just describe the steps I took to solve this:

1. You've already got the most important part -- find the variable with the information you need.
2. I notice immediately that this variable has a lot of data.  If I insert it into a buffer as a single line, Emacs will not be happy, because it's notoriously bad at handling long lines.  I know that the prett-print package will be able to format this data nicely.  So I open up my `*scratch*` buffer and run

   <kbd>M-: (insert (pp-to-string load-history))</kbd>
3. I can now see the data structure I'm dealing with.  It seems to be (in pseudo code):

   ```
   ((file-name
     ((defun|t|provide . symbol)|symbol)*)
    ...)
   ```
4. Now I just write the function

   ```
   (eval-when-compile (require 'cl))
   (defun locate-feature (feature)
     "Return file name as string where `feature' was provided"
     (interactive "Sfeature: ")
     (dolist (file-info load-history)
       (mapc (lambda (element)
               (when (and (consp element)
                          (eq (car element) 'provide)
                          (eq (cdr element) feature))
                 (when (called-interactively-p 'any)
                   (message "%s defined in %s" feature (car file-info)))
                 (return (car file-info))))
             (cdr file-info))))
   ```

   The code here is pretty straight forward.  Ask Emacs about the functions you don't understand.

### Method 2 help approach

Method one works for features.  But what if by I want to know where any
available function is defined?  Not just features.

<kbd>C-h f</kbd> already tells me that, but I want the file-name in a string, not all of the verbose help text.  I want this:

```
(defun locate-function (func)
  "Return file-name as string where `func' was defined or will be autoloaded"
  ...)
```

Here we go.

1. <kbd>C-h f</kbd> is my starting point, but I really want to read the code that defines `describe-function`.  I do this:

   <kbd>C-h k C-h f</kbd> <kbd>C-x o</kbd> <kbd>tab</kbd> <kbd>enter</kbd>
2. Now I'm in `help-fns.el` at the definition of `describe-function`.  I want to work only with this function definition.  So narrowing is in order:

   <kbd>C-x n d</kbd>
3. I have a hunch that the interesting command will have "find" or "locate" in its name, so I use `occur` to search for interesting lines:

   <kbd>M-s o</kbd> <kbd>find\|locate</kbd>

   No matches.  Hmmm.  Not a lot of lines in this defun.  `describe-function-1` seems to be doing the real work, so we try that.
4. I can visit the definition of `describe-function-1` via <kbd>C-h f</kbd>.  But I already have the file open.  `imenu` is available now:

   <kbd>C-x n w</kbd> <kbd>M-x imenu</kbd> <kbd>desc*1</kbd> <kbd>tab</kbd> <kbd>enter</kbd>
5. Narrow and search again:

   <kbd>C-x n d</kbd> <kbd>M-s o</kbd> <kbd>up</kbd> <kbd>enter</kbd>

   I see `find-lisp-object-file-name` which looks promising.
6. After reading <kbd>C-h f find-lisp-object-file-name</kbd> I come up with:

   ```
   (defun locate-function (func)
     "Return file-name as string where `func' was defined or will be autoloaded"
     (interactive "Ccommand: ")
     (let ((res (find-lisp-object-file-name func (symbol-function func))))
       (when (called-interactively-p 'any)
         (message "%s defined in %s" func res))
       res))
   ```

## Now go have some fun exploring Emacs.

Comment: great explanation and write up. both defuns are very useful for debugging. Could you make them interactive as well.? BTW your first defun has an extra closing parenthesis

Comment: I use `(symbol-file 'gnus)`. Second arg may be defun/defvar/defface

Answer (score 4):

There is `locate-library` for that.

Try...
<kbd>M-:</kbd> `(locate-library "my-feature")`

eg: `(locate-library "gnus")`

Comment: `locate-library` locates based on file-name.  While for the most part each file provides only one feature and the the feature is named after the file, **neither of these things have to be true**.

Answer (score 4):

Just use `symbol-file`. It scan `load-history` which has format:

```
Each entry has the form `(provide . FEATURE)',
`(require . FEATURE)', `(defun . FUNCTION)', `(autoload . SYMBOL)',
`(defface . SYMBOL)', or `(t . SYMBOL)'.  Entries like `(t . SYMBOL)'
may precede a `(defun . FUNCTION)' entry, and means that SYMBOL was an
autoload before this file redefined it as a function.  In addition,
entries may also be single symbols, which means that SYMBOL was
defined by `defvar' or `defconst'.
```

So call it as:

```
(symbol-file 'scheme 'provide)        ; Who provide feature.
(symbol-file 'nxml-mode-hook 'defvar) ; Where variable defined.
(symbol-file 'message-send 'defun)    ; Where function defined.
(symbol-file 'scheme)    ; Look for symbol despite its type.
```

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with it, but why is it simpler than getting help on a key or a function? If you use a gnus command for example and you want to know where it comes from then you can use `C-h k` and it tells you from which elisp file its definition comes.