# emacs interactive commands with default value

Tags: emacs, elisp, interactive

I am wondering how is that some interactive commands in emacs present default value while others don't. For instance when I am in C file and cursor stands on `printf`, running `manual-entry` will suggest showing manual page for `printf` by default. I would like to make my own interactive commands with default value. How?
It seems like thing-at-point is a good direction, but how do I blend thing-at-point and interactive together?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You already have good starting points to research your own solution.

`thing-at-point` is probably useful in this context.  I recently [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9620373/903943)
a question where I explained how to solve this type of problem by exploring the
Emacs code base.

Here is a rough toy function I came up with.

```lisp
(defun say-word (word)
  (interactive (list
                (read-string (format "word (%s): " (thing-at-point 'word))
                             nil nil (thing-at-point 'word))))
  (message "The word is %s" word))
```

One key thing here is to understand how the `interactive` form works.  I would
read the relevant [manual section](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Using-Interactive.html) carefully.

Comment: This seems like exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot!