# Custom interactive codes for interactive elisp function

Tags: elisp

I'm reading the [interactive codes](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Interactive-Codes.html#Interactive-Codes) section of the manual, and I'd really like to have something similar to `D` (default is the current default directory of the current buffer), but that uses the current buffer's file extension (if any).

Since there is no such default interactive code, I was wondering if there is a way to register new interactive codes.

Comment: possible duplicate of [emacs interactive commands with default value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9646088/emacs-interactive-commands-with-default-value)

Comment: What does "uses the current buffer's file extension" mean?

Comment: I'm guessing `(concat (directory-file-name default-directory) (file-name-extension (or (buffer-file-name) "") t))` ?

Comment: @sds: When editing a Python file, I usually want to search for stuff in other Python files, so the command should pass the `--include="*.py"` argument to the `grep` executable.

Comment: I think you are looking for the `rgrep` command.

Comment: @sds: Yeah, but the current context part doesn't work.  I can't make it default to the right folder or the right file extension.  Besides, this is mostly for educational purposes :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot add a new `interactive` code.

You would have to pass a form which evaluates to a list:

```
(interactive (list (read-directory-name "Enter directory" ...)))
```

Comment: I have to admit I was trying to keep the interactive string because I had other arguments.  It seems I need to use `read-string` for other arguments because `(interactive)` doesn't support a mixture of both.  Thanks for the help, this works for me :-)